# Codeigniter Build a Foreach query using Select_SUM on column values?

Tags: arrays, codeigniter, foreach, sum

I have successfully echoed the "1st CA", "2nd CA" and "Exam" on Codeigniter view. You'll find that in this images below

Report View and Code
[image: View report screenshot missing foreach query for Total Column]

Here is the View Code below

```
  <td bgcolor="#CCCCCC"><div align="center" class="style2"><?php
                    $obtained_second_ca_query = $this->db->get_where('mark' , array(
                                                'subject_id' => $row3['subject_id'],
                                                    'exam_id' => $exam_id,
                                                        'class_id' => $class_id,
                                                            'student_id' => $student_id , 
                                                                'year' => $this->db->get_where('settings' , array('type' => 'running_year'))->row()->description
                                            ));
                    if($obtained_second_ca_query->num_rows() > 0){
                        $marks2 = $obtained_second_ca_query->result_array();
                        foreach ($marks2 as $row4) {
                            echo $row4['second_ca'];
                            $total_marks += $row4['second_ca'];
                        }
                    }
                ?></div></td>
<td bgcolor="#CCCCCC"><div align="center" class="style2"></div></td>
<td bgcolor="#CCCCCC"><div align="center" class="style2"></div></td>
<td bgcolor="#CCCCCC"><div align="center" class="style2"></div></td>
<td bgcolor="#CCCCCC"><div align="center" class="style2"><?php
                    $obtained_exam_score_query = $this->db->get_where('mark' , array(
                                                'subject_id' => $row3['subject_id'],
                                                    'exam_id' => $exam_id,
                                                        'class_id' => $class_id,
                                                            'student_id' => $student_id , 
                                                                'year' => $this->db->get_where('settings' , array('type' => 'running_year'))->row()->description
                                            ));
                    if($obtained_exam_score_query->num_rows() > 0){
                        $marks3 = $obtained_exam_score_query->result_array();
                        foreach ($marks3 as $row4) {
                            echo $row4['exam_score'];
                            $total_marks += $row4['exam_score'];
                        }
                    }
                ?></div></td>
<td bgcolor="#CCCCCC"><div align="center" class="style2"><strong></strong></div></td>
```

However, I need to sum their values in the Total Column. Please help. thanks in advance.

Here is my database table ('mark') screenshot
[image: View my database table screenshot]

Also find my Model code below.

```
function get_obtained_marks( $exam_id , $class_id , $subject_id , $student_id) {
    $marks = $this->db->get_where('mark' , array(
                                'subject_id' => $subject_id,
                                    'exam_id' => $exam_id,
                                        'class_id' => $class_id,
                                            'student_id' => $student_id))->result_array();

    foreach ($marks as $row) {
        echo $row['mark_obtained'];
    }
}

function get_obtained_second_ca( $exam_id , $class_id , $subject_id , $student_id) {
    $marks2 = $this->db->get_where('mark' , array(
                                'subject_id' => $subject_id,
                                    'exam_id' => $exam_id,
                                        'class_id' => $class_id,
                                            'student_id' => $student_id))->result_array();

    foreach ($marks2 as $row) {
        echo $row['second_ca'];
    }
}

function get_obtained_exam_score( $exam_id , $class_id , $subject_id , $student_id) {
    $marks3 = $this->db->get_where('mark' , array(
                                'subject_id' => $subject_id,
                                    'exam_id' => $exam_id,
                                        'class_id' => $class_id,
                                            'student_id' => $student_id))->result_array();

    foreach ($marks3 as $row) {
        echo $row['exam_score'];
    }
```

Pls help with your solutions to this issue. I need a foreach query to sum 'mark_obtained' + 'second_ca' + 'exam_score' in my Total column.

Comment: this whole thing looks like a total mess, i'm not sure what exactly you want to achieve here - it certainly would help if you post more details from your view, controller, models and db structure - because it looks like you need help in order to organize your code

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. Actually I only need a FOREACH SELECT QUERY that can sum up the values in these columns ('mark_obtained' + 'second_ca' + 'exam_score').

Answer (score 0):

> Add select clause in each query.

```
$marks3 = $this->db->select('*,(mark_obtained + second_ca + exam_score) as total')->get_where('mark', array('subject_id' =>$subject_id, 'exam_id' => $exam_id,'class_id' => $class_id,'student_id' => $student_id))->result_array();
```

Comment: Hi Nitesh, I really appreciate your contribution, but I can't get your code to work. I inserted it in the <td></td> on my view page. Is there something I'm missing?

Comment: I know it's been 4 years and you've surely solved this by now, but for those who find this later... this is not code for the "view" file. This is code for the "model" file.